# 2+ out of 4 conditions regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 4 requirements for user passwords:

- At least 1 a-z char
- At least 1 A-Z char
- At least 1 0-9 char
- At least 1 symbol in `.!@#$%^&*()_`

However, user has to fulfill only 2+ of 4 conditions.

Passwords `VVVV1111`, `!234567`, `AaAaAaAa` or `A1!aA1!a` are valid, passwords `VVVVVVVV`, `12345678`, `aaaaaaa`, `!!!!!!!` are not.

How can I make 2 of 4 OR regexp?

I came up with this for 3 conditions (A-Z, a-z & 0-9):

```
^((?=.*?[A-Z])|(?=.*?[0-9]))((?=.*?[a-z])|((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]))).{8,30}$
```

But I think there has to be a better option because this regexp becomes really big with 4th condition.

Comment: Please don't put a maximum length on your passwords. That makes no sense. Also, put your condition logic _in if statements_. Use regex for simple limits, like character length.

Comment: I know right? But the client requires so..

Comment: Please may you advise your client that it goes against security best practices?

Comment: Advising mail is on the way sir

Comment: I can hear it flying already. (Not sure why I imagine mail flying...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always break down big problems into smaller ones.

Define a separate Regex for each of your four different conditions, then check if enough of them are fulfilled.

For example:

```
var checks = {
    lowercase: /[a-z]/,
    uppercase: /[A-Z]/,
    number: /[0-9]/,
    symbol: /[.!@#$%^&*()_]/
}, passcount = 0, results = {};
for( var k in checks) if( checks.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    if( checks[k].test(password)) {
        passcount++;
        results[k] = true;
    }
    else results[k] = false;
}
if( passcount < 2) {
    alert("Your password didn't meet enough conditions.\n" +
      "[Provide useful info here - 'results' object lists " +
      "whether each test passed or failed, so use that for " +
      "a user-friendly experience!]");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

And finally, obligatory xkcd comic:

[image: xkcd]

Comment: I guess performance difference against simple regex won't be an issue with this function..?

Comment: This isn't 1990, we have computers that can process billions of instructions per second. But if you really care, benchmark it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following expression:

```
/[a-z]/.test(pass)+/[A-Z]/.test(pass)+/\d/.test(pass)+/[.!@#$%^&*()_]/.test(pass)>2
```